# Force two decimal places in C#

Tags: c#

I've this problem and can't find a solution.
This is super easy and i don't know why can't i find a solution.

Problem:

- if a value returns for example "16.60", in c# i'll read "16.6", but i need 0 as well, because of paypal API, wich only accepts a value with no decimal numbers, or if it has to have decimal numbers the minimum and maximum must be 2.

So how can i make this?

i've tried this:

```
        string value_f = "16,6";
        decimal value_f_d = decimal.Parse(value_f);
        value_f_d = (decimal)Math.Round(value_f_d, 2);
        value_f = value_f_d.ToString("#.##");
        value_f = value_f.Replace(',', '.');
```

i want this output: **16.60**, but gives this: **16.6**

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the `ToString` overload that takes a format string? What does it tell you `#` means?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
string output = value_f_d.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(`using System.Globalization` in your using declarations at the top)

Comment: Additionally, consider using the InvariantCulture to format your number.  That avoids the necessity of replacing the decimal separator.  I.e. `var output = value_f_d.ToString("#.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @dbc, good call - answer updated. Thanks.