# Force decimal point and 0's after decimal with decimal.Parse

Tags: c#, decimalformat

I'm converting a string to a decimal with `decimal.Parse()`:

```
decimal.Parse(transactionAmount)
```

If `transactionAmount` contains a whole number such as `1`, the result is a decimal value of `1`. The system I'm sending it to outside of my program treats it as 1 cent for some unknown reason unless it shows up as `1.00`. How can I make sure that whole numbers contain a decimal point and a zero such as `1.0`?

Comment: If you are sending the `string` rather than the `decimal` you can format the `decimal` value with decimal places as needed and send that. If you are sending the `decimal` then the question gets stranger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` contains number of digits after the point as part of its internal presentation. So `1m` and `1.00m` are different `decimal values. As result all parsing/formatting operations will try to preserve that information coming from/to string form unless forced otherwise.

One hack to make sure there are *at least* two digits after decimal separator is to add proper 0 - `0.00m`:

```
    decimal decimalOne = decimal.Parse("1"); // 1.
    decimal decimalWithTwoDigit = decimalOne + 0.00m; // 1.00
```

Note that it is unusual to be *sending* decimal values in binary form to outside programs. Most likely you actually need to *format* decimal value with two digits only as covered in [Force two decimal places in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726689/force-two-decimal-places-in-c-sharp) - `.ToString("#.00")`.

Answer (score -2):

Try Convert.ToDecimal() instead of decimal.Parse()